# Syntax error in Python

Tags: python

```
pen_color = input("Enter a color name to set the pen color: ")
pen_width = input("Enter a number from 1-10 to set the pen width: ")
```

There is much more to it but it opens up and asks for a color and I type in a color then it just shuts down saying `Syntax error: Unexpected EOF while parsing.`

Comment: use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: Unless he/she's using Python 3.

Comment: Do these 2 lines form a program? What is the context? How does you input look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` prompts for a string, then `eval()`s it. Use `raw_input()`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x, [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) tries to evaluate the string that you enter as a Python expression. If that's not what you want, and you're using Python 2.x, you should use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of `input()`.

[This has changed in Python 3.x](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/), where `input()` no longer evaluates the input, and `raw_input()` no longer exists. Therefore in Python 3.x, [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) would be the correct function to use.

Answer (score 0):

**In Python 2.x**:
`input() = eval(raw_input())`
**In Python 3**
This is no longer the case, `input()` is same as `raw_input()` in Python 2.x.